# Access xampp from one computer to another computer via internet ip address

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I was trying to access my xampp from another computer ,it is showing as forbidden error.Then i googled for answer for that they were telling some settings to change in httpd.conf file which is there in apache folder as follows:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1

#Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.1
#Allow from ::1
```

But it is not working it still shows the same error.can somebody help me to solve this.

And i want access my xampp from multiple computers as well can you please provide a solution for this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try add new line

```
Allow from {other computer ip}
```

or for all

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

After change, restart xamp

Answer (score 0):

If you have domain available try assigning domain to your server IP

Worked for me at last