# Access Xampp from outside via Internet

Tags: web, xampp, hosting

I have an xampp installed in my system and i have a static ip address for my system.can i connect xampp through internet.which could be accessed through internet via static ip.. is there any possibilities and how to configure xampp and router to redirect to xampp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access local XAMPP from the Internet. Here are some great threads to follow.

[Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet)

[Access xampp from one computer to another computer via internet ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326293/access-xampp-from-one-computer-to-another-computer-via-internet-ip-address)